# Javascript gets only the first id from a foreach loop. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, loops

I use a foreach loop to get some tabs with different id's. This way I get tabs with ids tab1, tab2, tab3, etc. Than, when I want to get the id of each tab using javascript, it returns only the id of the first tab and uses this for all tabs. It does not loop as php do. Why?

```
<?php
foreach ($DB_con->query($foos) as $foo) {
    ?>
    <div id='tab<?php echo $counter_foo; ?>'>

    <div id="divid" style="visibility: hidden"><?php echo $counter_foo; ?></div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dividvalue = document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML;
        alert(dividvalue);
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: As per the usual, DOM ids **MUST** be unique, and since you're outputting multiple identical IDs, only the first one will ever be returned. that's why the function is called getElementByID, not getElement(s)ByID

Comment: [___There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.___](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand, I get different ids (like id="tab1", id="tab2", id="tab3", etc.) by using php. That is why I use foreach loop. How can we say "outputting multiple identical IDs"?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `id` in your HTML to `class`, and use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById` your in JavaScript.

Your div:

```
<div class="divid"> <!-- etc -->
```

and your JS..

```
var dividvalue = document.getElementsByClassName('divid')[0].innerHTML;
```

Also consider changing `divid` to `divclass` for consistency's sake.

Full edited code:

```
<script>
var i = 0;
</script>
<?php
foreach ($DB_con->query($foos) as $foo) {
    ?>
    <div id='tab<?php echo $counter_foo; ?>'>

    <div class="divclass" style="visibility: hidden"><?php echo $counter_foo; ?></div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var divclassvalue = document.getElementsByClassName('divclass')[i].innerHTML;
        alert(divclassvalue);
        i++;
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but localhost says "undefined"!

Comment: With the code var dividvalue = document.getElementsByClassName('divid')[0].innerHTML; I do not get any undefined result :-) But the problem is still the same: I always get the first ID!

Comment: I've updated the answer with the full code. Try that.

Comment: I tried the updated code but it doesn't alert anything! By the way, how do you use a php variable directly as an index of a javascript function?

Comment: My bad! I slipped up there. I've updated it to use a JavaScript counter instead, and I hope that works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But it started with 2 instead of 1. Then I changed the initial value to 0 as var i = 0; Now it is working perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get any coffee so my code was full of bugs yesterday! If you could mark my answer as accepted, I would be grateful.